# I cannot get the right UTF-8 encoding in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat7

I have a problem with UTF-8 character (for example ěčžýáí). I find some solutions on Stack Overflow but it doesn't work for me. Here is my Conf class. I'm not using web.xml, everything is via annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "cz.prosvaly")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }



}
```

Here is my filter for encoding:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();


        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = container.addFilter("encodingFilter",
                new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");


        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");

    }

}
```

Dispatcher config:

```
@Configuration
public class DispatcherConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
//        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/");
//        registry.addResourceHandler("/html/**").addResourceLocations("/html/");
//        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");   
        }
}
```

Spring security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).
      usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from admin where username=?").
      authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username =?  ")
      .passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
       .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
       .and().formLogin()
       .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/goods").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")        
       .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
       .and().csrf(); 
    }

}

public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
   //do nothing
}
```

In form that I'm sending on server I have this taglib:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

I tried update in Tomcat this row:

```
 <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

But when I submit the form I see this in the log

```
....type for Å¾ÄÃ¡Ã­Å¾Ã­Ã©
```

Comment: With which HTTP method do you submit ? POST or GET ? URIEncoding="UTF-8" is for get while the CharacterEncodingFilter is for post.

Comment: It is not convention to mark solution this way on SO. Post solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP:)*

I have to deleted SpringSecurityInitializer and create filter via the following code in in `AppInitializer`:

```
fr = container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",
                new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
```